# Using raw socket to access ethernet MAC address through structure

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am trying to create a packet sniffer on linux. I want to be able to print the Source MAC and Dest MAC. I have been looking around and most of the code prints out the bytes in the ethernet header based on index. So for example..

```
sock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));

bytes = recvfrom(sock, buf, 1024, 0, &saddr, &saddrsize);

struct ether_header *eth = (struct ether_header *)buf;
printf("MAC DEST: %x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x\n", eth->ether_dhost[0], eth->ether_dhost[1], eth->ether_dhost[2], eth->ether_dhost[3], eth->ether_dhost[4], eth->ether_dhost[5],);
```

I was wondering if it is possible to print just the dhost without doing each individual index? I am eventually going to want to get src mac, dst mac, src ip, dst ip, port, protocol. So I just wanted to check if it had to be done like above, or if it could be easier.

EDIT:Added socket()

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't get anything about the physical or data-link layer using `recvfrom()`. You're going to need to go to a lower level. Have you tried using `libpcap`?

Comment: recvfrom will give me the entire packet. I can get the mac right now doing the above. I just was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Comment: @tadman It depends on how you open the socket.

Comment: The cleaner solution would be `libpcap` but barring that, what could you improve there? You've got three lines of code. You want two?

Comment: @DanielH I'm used to using `SOCK_RAW` but even that doesn't give Ethernet info, just raw IP. Is this with `AF_PACKET`?

Comment: @tadman I haven’t done this in a while so I might misremember the details, but `SOCK_RAW` with `AF_PACKET` should give the layer 2 header as well. How do you think `libpcap` does it?

Comment: @tadman I don't want libpcap. And cleaner would be something like eth->ether_dhost, which then prints the entire mac. Instead of doing one index at a time.

Comment: Are you asking how to avoid typing out the 6x array accesses in the `printf()` call? Try a for loop?... I don't know of another way to get the format you're after.

Comment: Also, you should use `%02x` to make sure there are always two hexadecimal characters/digits, and probably `%02hhx` as I imagine the type is 8-bit unsigned.

Comment: @Attie Yeah that is what I am trying to prevent. I don't want to have to print out each. I was hoping it was a easier method like i mentioned above.

Comment: (Especially the highest-voted non-accepted answer, which I think is what you want)

Comment: @DanielH That is exactly what I wanted. This just makes the code look cleaner imo. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielH Actually that just puts me back into the same boat. That ether_ntoa just prints each byte each like my question. And it doesn't pad the zeros. So looks like printing each is what I will be doing. Thank you though for your help.

Comment: @DanielH Just checking that this was initialized correctly and it's not just dumping stuff from the wrong layer under the presumption it's actually a MAC address.